# How to access to the internal state of cache2k

Tags: java, cache2k

I'm currently using the version 1.2.0.Final of cache2k. I want to persist the internal state of the cache so that my application can reuse the cache content after restarting.  I've walked through the [API](https://cache2k.org/docs/1.0/apidocs/cache2k-api/index.html) of cache2k but I didn't find any possibility to do that. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistence is there but "it is not yet production ready"

see also [How to define persistence storage in cache2k?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36916528/how-to-define-persistence-storage-in-cache2k) and https://github.com/cache2k/cache2k/issues/30